# Generic property-list with any generic argument

Tags: c#, generics

I need to instantiate a list-property where the generic type can be anything.

So my `Main`-method looks like this: (In real, `ParsingObject<T>` are objects I get from a service)

```
public static void Main()
{
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    parser.AddAnObject(
        new ParsingObject<int>{PropertyName = "FirstProperty", Active=true, DefaultValue=1}
    );
    parser.AddAnObject(
        new ParsingObject<bool>{PropertyName = "SecondProperty", Active=false, DefaultValue=false}
    );
    parser.Parse();
}
```

`ParsingObject` gets any type (I think only string, bool, int,...)  as generic. Now in my parser I need to add this object into a `List<ParsingObject<T>>` like:

```
public class Parser
{
    private readonly List<ParsingObject<T>> _listOfObjects = new List<ParsingObject<T>>();

    public void AddAnObject<T>(ParsingObject<T> item)
    {
        _listOfObjects.Add(item);
    }

    public void Parse()
    {
        foreach(var item in _listOfObjects.Where(w=>Active))
        {
            DoSomething(item);
        }
    }
}
```

but I know, I cannot set `T` as generic argument when instantiating the list (compiler is crying..). 
So I could solve this with using `ArrayList` - but then I can't access the properties of each object. (See the `Parse()`-method)

for completeness, here is my `ParsingObject<T>`-class:

```
public class ParsingObject<T>
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

Any idea how I could solve this? I cannot modify the `ParsingObject<T>`-class.

Comment: tada! You've now realized the limitation of this generic pattern.

Comment: Not really - when you think about it it obviously cannot work! how would `_listOfObjects` know whether the next item is an `int` or `string`

Comment: It would also be useful to know what you are planning to do with those objects. You obviously cannot use them in general form without casting, so maybe using `object` type to store value and separate property for storing `Type` instead of generics would be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly is your end goal, maybe something like this would be sufficient:

```
public class ParsingObjectBase
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Type ValueType { get; protected set; }

    public object DefVal { get; protected set; }
}
public class ParsingObject<T> : ParsingObjectBase
{
    public object DefaultValue
    {
        get { return (T)DefVal; }
        set { DefVal = value; }
    }

    public ParsingObject()
    {
        ValueType = typeof(T);
    }
}

private readonly List<ParsingObjectBase> _listOfObjects = new List<ParsingObjectBase>();

public void AddAnObject<T>(ParsingObject<T> item)
{
    _listOfObjects.Add(item);
}

public void Parse()
{
    foreach(var item in _listOfObjects.Where(w=>w.Active))
    {
        DoSomething(item); //do what exactly?
    }
}
```

You obviously can't do without casting either to concrete `ParsingObject<T>` or `DefVal` value in this case, but you have `Type` information stored in one place and have access to your specific properties. Maybe changing `ValueType` to some kind of `enum` would be easier to use with `switch`?

Comment: Sounds like a solution. Is there a way to get an object from `ParsingObjectBase` back to `ParsingObject<T>` ?

Comment: @Matthias you need to cast, unfortunately. This implies you need to know the type, thus my remark about `switch` (or perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368486/generic-property-list-with-any-generic-argument/39369062#39369062))

Comment: I got it finally. Thanks for helping :)